# When I append XSS filtered html, it prints raw html

Tags: javascript, xssf

Here's XSS filtering JavaScript code

```
var XSSfilter = function( content ) {
return content.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");};
```

and append source below

```
function send_msg(nick, msg) {
var html = '<div class="msg_box"><img class="profile-pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/.jpg">
<div class="user_name_chat">{NAME}</div>
<div class="text">{MESSAGE}</div><div class="clear"></div>';
var append = html.replace('{NAME}', nick);
html = append.replace('{MESSAGE}', msg);
console.log(html);
$('#messages').append(XSSFilter(html));}
```

When I append this, it doesn't append `<b>HTML</b>`, it appends `<b>string</b>` instead.

What I want : `img+nick+msg`

result : `<div class="msg_box" ....`

Any solutions about this problem?

Comment: Why would you expect `img+nick+msg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](https://jsfiddle.net/f1m5cwwd/)***

First, `Uncaught ReferenceError: XSSFilter is not defined`. You need to make sure the function name matches your call. Either change the function name to `XSSFilter` or call it with `XSSfilter` - I would assume the former.

Okay, now beyond that. When you use `console.log` it is going to actually call `toString()` on the argument. The result is that you don't see your regex is actually converting the `<div>` to `&lt;div&gt;` which is not valid html and as a result is appended as a string by jQuery.

The best approach would be to only filter the part that is being input (the nick and the message).

```js
var XSSFilter = function( content ) {
return content.replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
};

function send_msg(nick, msg) {
  nick = XSSFilter(nick);
  msg = XSSFilter(msg);
  var html = '<div class="msg_box"><img class="profile-pic" src="http://i.imgur.com/.jpg"><div class="user_name_chat">{NAME}</div><div class="text">{MESSAGE}</div><div class="clear"></div>';
  var append = html.replace('{NAME}', nick);
  html = append.replace('{MESSAGE}', msg);
  console.log(html);
  $('#messages').append(html);
}

send_msg('nick','msg');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to filter for XSS, and the approach you are trying to take, is to treat user input as *plain text* and convert it to an HTML representation of that text.

Your problem is that you are taking user input, putting it into your template, then passing the result through the XSS filter… but the output of the template is supposed to be HTML not plain text.

You need to change from this:

1. Put user input into template
2. Filter output of template for XSS
3. Use output of XSS filter

to this:

1. Filter each piece of user input for XSS
2. Put filtered input into template
3. Use HTML output of template